# Manipulate with XML data

Tags: c#, xml

In my `DB` I have a couple of field like: `Name`,`Address`,`Email`,`Phone`,`Post Code` etc...
And my output of `XML` look like this one:

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="MJESTO" msprop:BaseTable.0="AKONTAS">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="A_KONTO" msprop:BaseColumn="A_KONTO" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="NAZIV" msprop:BaseColumn="NAZIV" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="SIFRA_RAD" msprop:BaseColumn="SIFRA_RAD" msprop:OraDbType="104" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="OPSTINA" msprop:BaseColumn="OPSTINA" msprop:OraDbType="104" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MB" msprop:BaseColumn="MB" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ULICA" msprop:BaseColumn="ULICA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="BROJ" msprop:BaseColumn="BROJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PBROJ" msprop:BaseColumn="PBROJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MJESTO" msprop:BaseColumn="MJESTO" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PORESKI" msprop:BaseColumn="PORESKI" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TRANSAKCIJ" msprop:BaseColumn="TRANSAKCIJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="INTERNET" msprop:BaseColumn="INTERNET" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="EMAIL" msprop:BaseColumn="EMAIL" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="KONTAKT" msprop:BaseColumn="KONTAKT" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TELEFON" msprop:BaseColumn="TELEFON" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="FAKS" msprop:BaseColumn="FAKS" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DAT_UNOS" msprop:BaseColumn="DAT_UNOS" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PDVMB" msprop:BaseColumn="PDVMB" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="VRSTA_KLIJENTA" msprop:BaseColumn="VRSTA_KLIJENTA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DRZAVA" msprop:BaseColumn="DRZAVA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<MJESTO diffgr:id="MJESTO1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<A_KONTO>517173</A_KONTO>
<NAZIV>abc"</NAZIV>
<SIFRA_RAD>50041</SIFRA_RAD>
<MB>12333333</MB>
<ULICA>xyx</ULICA>
<BROJ>51</BROJ>
<PBROJ>72000</PBROJ>
<MJESTO>City A</MJESTO>
<DAT_UNOS>2011-10-19T00:00:00+02:00</DAT_UNOS>
<PDVMB>218218020003</PDVMB>
<DRZAVA>06</DRZAVA>
</MJESTO>
<MJESTO diffgr:id="MJESTO2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<A_KONTO>517174</A_KONTO>
<NAZIV>Name 1</NAZIV>
<SIFRA_RAD>50041</SIFRA_RAD>
<MB>123654789</MB>
<ULICA>Asca</ULICA>
<BROJ>8</BROJ>
<PBROJ>72000</PBROJ>
<MJESTO>Huhu</MJESTO>
<DAT_UNOS>2011-10-25T00:00:00+02:00</DAT_UNOS>
<DRZAVA>06</DRZAVA>
</MJESTO>
<MJESTO diffgr:id="MJESTO3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<A_KONTO>517175</A_KONTO>
<NAZIV>abcde</NAZIV>
<SIFRA_RAD>50041</SIFRA_RAD>
<MB>123333344444</MB>
<ULICA>Address1</ULICA>
<BROJ>4</BROJ>
<PBROJ>72000</PBROJ>
<MJESTO>Vityuz</MJESTO>
<DAT_UNOS>2011-10-26T00:00:00+02:00</DAT_UNOS>
<DRZAVA>06</DRZAVA>
```

And right now I want to create of edit existing code that pass which field I want to display, maybe some of these field is necessary some of another field is more important. As I check `DataSet` return only field from database which is `NOT NULL`, and field which is NULL doesn't return. 
I want to modify this existing function that works manuely, so I want to pass which field from database I want to retrieve.

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet GetAkontasByMjesto(string Mjesto)
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=test-1:1521/fba;USER ID=test;PASSWORD=test");
    OracleDataAdapter dr = new OracleDataAdapter("Select * from AKONTAS where lower(MJESTO) ='" + Mjesto.ToLower() + "'", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add("MJESTO");
    dr.Fill(ds, "MJESTO");
    DataTable tt = ds.Tables[0];
    return ds;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MJESTO diffgr:id="MJESTO1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <A_KONTO>517173</A_KONTO>
  <NAZIV>abc"</NAZIV>
  <SIFRA_RAD>50041</SIFRA_RAD>
  <MB>12333333</MB>
  <ULICA>xyx</ULICA>
  <BROJ>51</BROJ>
  <PBROJ>72000</PBROJ>
  <MJESTO>City A</MJESTO>
  <DAT_UNOS>2011-10-19T00:00:00+02:00</DAT_UNOS>
  <PDVMB>218218020003</PDVMB>
  <DRZAVA>06</DRZAVA>
</MJESTO>
<MJESTO diffgr:id="MJESTO1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <A_KONTO>517173</A_KONTO>
  <NAZIV>abc"</NAZIV>
  <SIFRA_RAD>50041</SIFRA_RAD>
  <MB>12333333</MB>
  <ULICA>xyx</ULICA>
  <BROJ>51</BROJ>
  <PBROJ>72000</PBROJ>
  <MJESTO>City A</MJESTO>
  <DAT_UNOS>2011-10-19T00:00:00+02:00</DAT_UNOS>
  <PDVMB>218218020003</PDVMB>
  <DRZAVA>06</DRZAVA>
</MJESTO>
<MJESTO diffgr:id="MJESTO1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <A_KONTO>517173</A_KONTO>
  <NAZIV>abc"</NAZIV>
  <SIFRA_RAD>50041</SIFRA_RAD>
  <MB>12333333</MB>
  <ULICA>xyx</ULICA>
  <BROJ>51</BROJ>
  <PBROJ>72000</PBROJ>
  <MJESTO>City A</MJESTO>
  <DAT_UNOS>2011-10-19T00:00:00+02:00</DAT_UNOS>
  <PDVMB>218218020003</PDVMB>
  <DRZAVA>06</DRZAVA>
</MJESTO>
<MJESTO diffgr:id="MJESTO1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <A_KONTO>517173</A_KONTO>
  <NAZIV>abc"</NAZIV>
  <SIFRA_RAD>50041</SIFRA_RAD>
  <MB>12333333</MB>
  <ULICA>xyx</ULICA>
  <BROJ>51</BROJ>
  <PBROJ>72000</PBROJ>
  <MJESTO>City A</MJESTO>
  <DAT_UNOS>2011-10-19T00:00:00+02:00</DAT_UNOS>
  <PDVMB>218218020003</PDVMB>
  <DRZAVA>06</DRZAVA>
</MJESTO
```

>

Comment: The query is returning only values where the Mjesto matches.  So I do not know what you mean by NULL.  If you are not getting all the data, the issue is more likely putting the data into the database than querying the database.

Comment: Sure, but I want to  create these `.xml` manually and display only field what I need it.

Comment: Something like this: 
http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/img/product.JPG

Comment: Instead of using "Select *" specify only the columns you want instead of the asterisk.

Comment: Is there  possible that user create .xml file and create function to populate these xml with data from db ?

Comment: Your xml has an embedded schema and xml data.  Your answer is yes.  The xml will probably have database name, table, and fields.  You may need a join if data is coming from more than one table.

Comment: No, it comes only from one table. It needs to containt whaever

Comment: What help do you need?

Comment: I  have no idea, since I have never done before this staff, manipulating with XML
I need help how to  manully populate XML file from database.

Comment: So start by creating the template xml that you want filled in.  Post sample of the xml and then I will help.  You will notice the xml posted has the table name "MJESTO".  So you would take you template and create a query to database using the xml input.  Then take results an fill in xml with data.

Comment: @Thank you,I will post XML template when I finish :)

Comment: @jdweng I update my question, you can check right now

Comment: I'm not super familiar with oracle connections in particular, but you probably shouldn't be passing a value directly through your select statement like that...it's prone to SQL injection attacks....also what happens if `Mjesto` contains a single quote in it?  Additionally, unless you're literally using every field in a table, you shouldn't use `Select *` because you're pulling unused data across the query, which may lead to performance problems.

Comment: You posted xml is not well formed because there is an array at the root level.  It can be read but not sure if that is the way you want to go.  I was assuming the xml would  be a template without any data.  Maybe just the schema section of original xml with "xs:element" containing the column names.

Comment: @user2366842 I am familiar with this, but this is only for test purpose

Comment: @jdweng Provide `xml`  template in your own, whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start.  See if it is acceptable?

XML input.  This is the deluxe version   Can be simpler   :

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="MJESTO" msprop:BaseTable.0="AKONTAS">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="A_KONTO" msprop:BaseColumn="A_KONTO" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="NAZIV" msprop:BaseColumn="NAZIV" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="SIFRA_RAD" msprop:BaseColumn="SIFRA_RAD" msprop:OraDbType="104" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="OPSTINA" msprop:BaseColumn="OPSTINA" msprop:OraDbType="104" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="MB" msprop:BaseColumn="MB" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="ULICA" msprop:BaseColumn="ULICA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="BROJ" msprop:BaseColumn="BROJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="PBROJ" msprop:BaseColumn="PBROJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="MJESTO" msprop:BaseColumn="MJESTO" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="PORESKI" msprop:BaseColumn="PORESKI" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="TRANSAKCIJ" msprop:BaseColumn="TRANSAKCIJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="INTERNET" msprop:BaseColumn="INTERNET" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="EMAIL" msprop:BaseColumn="EMAIL" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="KONTAKT" msprop:BaseColumn="KONTAKT" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="TELEFON" msprop:BaseColumn="TELEFON" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="FAKS" msprop:BaseColumn="FAKS" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="DAT_UNOS" msprop:BaseColumn="DAT_UNOS" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="PDVMB" msprop:BaseColumn="PDVMB" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="VRSTA_KLIJENTA" msprop:BaseColumn="VRSTA_KLIJENTA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="DRZAVA" msprop:BaseColumn="DRZAVA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Here is c# code for read and creating a query :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string TABLE_NAME = "MJESTO";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement schema = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "schema").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace xs = schema.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xs");

            XElement sequence = doc.Descendants(xs + "sequence").FirstOrDefault();

            string[] columnNames = sequence.Elements(xs + "element").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("name")).ToArray();

            string query = string.Format("Select {0} FROM {1}", string.Join(",", columnNames), TABLE_NAME);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a different approach that is similar using same template :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);

            DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
            string[] columnNames = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();
            string query = string.Format("Select {0} FROM {1}", string.Join(",", columnNames), table.TableName);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When I run application, consol just open and close 
When I look at in file, nothing inside

Comment: Did you query the database?  Did you save the results after the query?  I just created the query that is based on the template.

Comment: You mean this line
string query = string.Format("Select {0} FROM {1}", string.Join(",", columnNames), TABLE_NAME);

Comment: string query = string.Format("Select * FROM AKONTO", string.Join(",", columnNames), TABLE_NAME);

Comment: You only want specific columns so you should not be using the asterisk.  Use my query instead.

Comment: I change it to column, but still nothing happened

Comment: What is the difference between your query string and mine?  Looks like mine may need a little change.  Columns names must be exactly the same as the database.

Comment: I updated query and now look like this
string query = string.Format("Select A_KONTO,NAZIV,SIFRA_RAD FROM AKONTAS", string.Join(",", columnNames), TABLE_NAME);

Comment: No, console just open and close.

Comment: Try debugging and let me know if I can help.  Once you change the query it should run similar to old code.